# JavaScript: Find object with Highest & Lowest

Tags: javascript

This seemed pretty straight forward,so I was surprised when it did not work.  I am trying to find the object with the highest and lowest 'price'.  First, please confirm or correct my logic. If, the logic is correct, then please suggest what might be the problem.

```
var high;
var low;
var j=0;
for (i in obj) {
    //alert(obj[i].price);
    if(j===0){
        high=obj[i].price; low=obj[i].price
    }else{
        if(obj[i].price > high){high=obj[i].price}
        if(obj[i].price < low ){low =obj[i].price}
    }
    alert("high: " + high +", low: " +low);
    j++;
}
```

Note: This works fine: `for (i in obj) {` There is another portion of the script that cycles through the list perfectly and with this methodology.

Comment: This is probably not the case, but is `obj` an array? If so, you can make this a lot more concise with some helper functions.

Comment: [The code looks to me as if it works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/KLBmD/)

Comment: Show use your varaible `obj`.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.max` and `Math.min` are built-in methods that can be used to find the highest or lowest numbers from the arguments passed.  One technique that you can use with these functions is applying them to an array of numbers.

What you have should perform just fine, but if you're looking for something more concise, here's an example of the technique:

```
var arr = [],
    high, low;

for (var i in obj)
    arr.push(obj[i].price);

high = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
low  = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
```

> Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cCexG/

You may also want to add a `hasOwnProperty()` check to prevent from iterating over enumerable inherited properties.  This could possibly be the cause of your current problem, either that or the missing `var` keyword for the `i` variable.

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i) && obj[i].price)
        arr.push(obj[i].price);
}
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is for ES3 losers. ES5 winners use `Object.keys(obj).map(function (o) { return o.price; })`

Comment: @Raynos: What do you mean? `Object.keys` returns an array of strings, namely the keys. Those *keys* don't have a `price` property.

Comment: @pimvdb >_< `.map(function (k) { return obj[k].price; })` my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort the array of objects by price in this way:

```
objects.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.price < b.price ? -1 : 1
});
```

the code above will sort objects by brice ascending (replace "<" with ">" for descending order)... then you can access the lowest with: **objects[0]** and the highest with: **objects[objects.length-1]**

Comment: This assumes that `objects` is an array, which is unclear at this point.

Comment: This can be inefficient because *all* elements are sorted, but you're only looking for the lowest/highest.

Comment: Yes, I assumed (erroneously) that he was iterate on an array :P

Answer (score 0):

Edit: is working now. I was just going to point out the Math.min() and max but someone beat me to it ;)!

```
var prices = ["110.5", "110", "350", "255.13", "350.5", "256"];

document.writeln(prices.sort(sortASC));
document.writeln(prices.sort(sortDESC));

function sortASC(a,b){
    return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
}

function sortDESC(a,b){
    return parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9BSeF/

Comment: Not working, at least not by default, since there is no `Object.prototype.sort`.

Comment: Edited post. Like Andy E mentioned, math.min and max is the way to go!